# How make ajax-request from service?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular

Please help fix service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class RecordsService {

  constructor(private http: Http){ }

  getRecords(dateBeginUnix, dateEndUnix): Object {
    console.log(dateBeginUnix, dateEndUnix);
    let result = this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/days/' + dateBeginUnix + '/' + dateEndUnix);
    console.log('result', result);
    return result;
  } 

}
```

component:

```
export class PanelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private recordsService: RecordsService) { }

  private modelDateBegin: Object;  
  private modelDateEnd: Object;  
  private records: Object;  
  private data: Object;  

  displayStatistic() {
    this.recordsService
        .getRecords(this.modelDateBegin['epoc'], this.modelDateBegin['epoc'])
        .subscribe((data: Response) => this.records = data.json());
  }

}
```

Console display follow errormessage:

> ERROR in /home/kalinin/angular2/rurun/src/app/panel/panel.component.ts
>   (31,10): Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Object'.

In component modelDateBegin['epoc'] and modelDateBegin['epoc'] contains unix datestamp.

Address:

```
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/days/' + dateBeginUnix + '/' + dateEndUnix
```

is return data in json-format.

But console display errormessage...

Comment: Change Object return type to Observable<any>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your getRecords should return a `Observable` not `Object` , only Observable can be subscribe not Object , try this

```
getRecords(dateBeginUnix, dateEndUnix): Observable<any>{
    console.log(dateBeginUnix, dateEndUnix);
    let result = this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/days/' + dateBeginUnix + '/' + dateEndUnix);
    console.log('result', result);
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but console display: '
/home/kalinin/angular2/rurun/src/app/records.service.ts (9,43): Cannot find name 'Observable'.'

Comment: You have to import Observable from `rx` , please search for any Observable examples